# MarkLogic document identity column

Tags: java, marklogic, nosql

Coming from the relational world, I am looking at using some sort of identity / auto-increment mechanism for the id field of my documents. Is there anything in MarkLogic that sets this?

Secondly, is it then appropriate to use said id field in the URI when document is PUT in ML (ie. /books/123)?

Comment: A quick perusal of the docs (you looked, right?) indicates documents are identified by a unique URI which serves as the identifier.  The documentation covers generation of unique URIs for newly created documents.  Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Can you please post the link of the documentation for generating unique URIs?

Comment: Please learn how to do your own research.  Questions that can be answered with "here's a link to the documentation" are considered off-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: Fair enough. But I cannot seem to find a doc for the MarkLogic Java API client (via annotation or  whatever) to make this happen...

Comment: MarkLogic website, click the "Developers" link at the top, then Documentation

Comment: Thanks mate, that did help. To add, once in the Documentation, select "Section = Java Client API". Then in the filter box, type in "generate". It leads to this: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/document-operations#id_74963. Basically its saying to use DocumentUriTemplate (will try in a sec). Happy to mark this as closed or off-topic if required.

Answer (score 3):

A document's unique identifier is its URI. A URI can be (almost) any string. However there are several conventions that most people use when implementing a strategy to define URIs. For example, you can use slashes like UNIX paths, to define (implicit) directories. It's also helpful to add an extension, like `.xml` or `.json` to indicate the mime type of the document.

I'd advise you to stay away from sequential identifiers. You'll need to lock on whatever is generating the numbers. In a distributed system, like MarkLogic, that guarantees consistency, this is expensive. Sequential numbers also make it more difficult to integrate data. What if another collection of books starts at the same seed?

I'd suggest using something like a UUID in your URIs to provide global uniqueness without locking.

Comment: Thanks Justin. I was just wondering since I've decided to use PojoRepository wherein a Pojo needs to have an @Id (which corresponds to the document's uri ), is there a way for me to use the DocumentUriTemplate with this (i.e. call some method from the template that would return the unique uri)?

Comment: @CarlosJaimeC.DeLeon no, there's no integration between DocumentUriTemplate and PojoRepository since PojoRepository generates the URI base on its own rules.  How about using java.util.UUID to generate the ids?